# how to set image and info side by side in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am stuck in a problem when am trying to set image and text side by side then its not shown perfect , checkout below I shared my code.

This is my image

https://ibb.co/SKS3bJM

i want like this

https://ibb.co/RhFkbkX

> index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
            <img src="Images/twitter.jpg" style="width: 200px;">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <h4>Should Twitter Get Rid of Follower Counts?</h4>
                <p>The possibility feels closer than ever</p>
                <p>Cool Neha in All Things Creative</p>
                <p><b>JAN 9. 5 min read</b></p>

            </div>
           
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"  style="height: 50px;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="display: flex; ">
                    <img src="Images/html.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    <p>Html, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on WWW pages.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="display: flex;">
                    <img src="Images/cs.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    <p>Html, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on WWW pages.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="display: flex;">
                    <img src="Images/js.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    <p>Html, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on WWW pages.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4  mt-2">
            <img src="Images/cofee.png" style="width: 350px;">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <h4>No,That's Not How You Say It.</h4>
                <p>A short Personal history of my favourite fast Food.</p>
                <p>VIP Singh</p>
                <p><b>JAN 29. 8 min read</b></p>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Monu, welcome to Stack Overflow. The next time try to be more specific with your question and focus on the part of your HTML that is behaving wrong. This way you'll get more answers. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the center column is being squished too much. This is because each image-text pair was inside a div with `class="col-sm-4"`. This was making the div too narrow. If you remove the class, the problem will disappear.

This is the resulting code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
            <img src="Images/twitter.jpg" style="width: 200px;">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <h4>Should Twitter Get Rid of Follower Counts?</h4>
                <p>The possibility feels closer than ever</p>
                <p>Cool Neha in All Things Creative</p>
                <p><b>JAN 9. 5 min read</b></p>

            </div>
           
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"  style="height: 50px;">
                <div class="" style="display: flex; ">
                    <img src="Images/html.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    <p>Html, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on WWW pages.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="" style="display: flex;">
                    <img src="Images/cs.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    <p>Html, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on WWW pages.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="" style="display: flex;">
                    <img src="Images/js.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                    <p>Html, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on WWW pages.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4  mt-2">
            <img src="Images/cofee.png" style="width: 350px;">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <h4>No,That's Not How You Say It.</h4>
                <p>A short Personal history of my favourite fast Food.</p>
                <p>VIP Singh</p>
                <p><b>JAN 29. 8 min read</b></p>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```